# Can CSS media queries refer to the container width?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, container-queries

I develop Javascript interactives for a publication that [has a 325px left navigation rail](http://time.com/93911/baby-name-predictor/) on desktop that gets hidden if the width of the page goes below 800px.

This means the space for the content on the right, where my interactives go, accordions in width like so:

**Above 800px total page width**, the content well is (width - 325px). Not counting the margins, this gets down to about 380px just before the breakpoint activates.

**Below 800px**, the content gets the whole width of the page.

I use basic `min-width` and `max-width` CSS media queries to govern the page's behavior for different screen-sizes. All I care about is the width of the interactive, and I would prefer not to have to hard code in the breakpoints written into the CMS (which could change without notice.)

Is there any way for `@media (max-width: 600px)` to refer to a container's width, not the width of the page?

Comment: No...not yet. It's been suggested but not likely to be seen for some time. - http://responsiveimagescg.github.io/eq-usecases/

Comment: Good article about this by Ian Taylor - http://ianstormtaylor.com/media-queries-are-a-hack/ might be worth reading. It would be nice if `@element` was eventually included in the spec.

Comment: Currently not possible, in my article http://d6u.github.io/react-container-query/, I listed some polyfills for that.